# Cannot show data from controller to email blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to show $data form controller to view but it shows this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWedk.png). Do you know why and how to fix that? Thank you.

Here's my code:

**UserController.php**

```
public function forgotPassword(Request $request){
  $data['user']['email'] = $request->input('user.email'); 
  Mail::send('vendor.notifications.resetpassword', $data, function($message) use($data){
       $message->from('bemsadmin@gmail.com');
       $message->to($data ['user']['email']);
       $message->subject('Your Email');
  });
  return response()->json($data);
}
```

**resetpassword.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <body>
    <p>{{$data['user']['email']}}</p>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the error happens beacuse you did not pass a variable called `$data` to the email view,

you pass a variable like this

`Mail::send('vendor.notifications.resetpassword', ['data' => $data], function($message) use($data){`

but with your code what get passed is

`['user' => ['email' => 'email@examle.com']]`

so try in your view to use the following code, it should do the job.

`{{$user['email']}}`